# Sonarqube scan ends with "INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL" but sonarqube UI says "Project is not analyzed yet."

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I have a jenkins job that is triggered when a PR is made to a bitbucket repository. The job will run a sonarqube scan of the repository.

Then, I use sonarqube plugin called [sonar-for-bitbucket](https://github.com/mibexsoftware/sonar-bitbucket-plugin) that will make a PR comment summarizing the analysis.

This part happens successfully.

[image]

This is my sonarqube configuration in jenkins.

[image]

This is the console output

```
...
INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL
INFO: Executing post-job Sonar Plug-in for Bitbucket Cloud
INFO: [sonar4bitbucket] Plug-in is active and will analyze pull request with #199...
INFO: Task total time: 1:25.408 s
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 1:27.292s
INFO: Final Memory: 64M/827M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
WARN: Unable to locate 'report-task.txt' in the workspace. Did the SonarScanner succedeed?
Finished: SUCCESS
```

However, when I go to sonarqube UI it doesn't show any analysis result.

[image]

I also tried running this from my macbook with `sonar-scanner`. Got the same result.

```
INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL
INFO: Task total time: 35.944 s
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 2:50.449s
INFO: Final Memory: 28M/813M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What about the report-task.txt warning?